# Как настроить https для Apache и Tomcat бесплатным сертификатом?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, ssl, https

**Дано:**

`VPS` на `Ubuntu`, на нём `Apache` (для фронта) и `Tomcat` (для API). Есть домен, всё работает для `http`.

**Задача:**

Настроить `https` доступ.

**Проблема:**

Не хочется платить за сертификат.

**Вопрос:**

Как получить бесплатный сертификат и всё настроить?

Comment: Заголовок не соответствует вопросу и ответу, сертификаты letsencrypt не являются самоподписанными

Comment: @andreymal, вполне возможно) Однако, для меня лично, как мало понимающего в этой теме человека, именно такой заголовок кажется тем, что мне нужно, если мне нужен бесплатный сертификат) Но, в целом, против изменения заголовка не буду протестовать.

Comment: Если проблема именно в том, что не хочется платить за сертификат, то чем плох LetsEncrypt? Если нужен бесплатный сертификат, то почему вопрос про самоподписанный?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, если я правильно понял что я сделал, то у меня как раз таки LetsEncrypt... Похоже только я считал, что это самоподписанный сертификат) Заменю в заголовке это слово на бесплатный)

Comment: Похоже, что да. Самоподписанный сертификат — это несколько другое :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас должен быть `root` доступ к серверу через `ssh`.
2. Устанавливаем программу [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). Она c открытыми [исходниками](https://github.com/certbot/certbot) и позволяет автоматически сгенерировать, установить и обновлять `SSL` сертификат для `Apache`

   (Инструкции с сайта программы, [для Apache и Ubuntu 18.04](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache), там же есть для других программ и ОС):

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-apache
   ```
3. Запускаем для `Apache`

   ```
   sudo certbot --apache
   ```

   Запустится программа, которая за несколько шагов всё настроит, сгенерировав файлы сертификата и прописав его в конфигурацию `Apache`. В конце расскажет, где лежат сгенерированные файлы сертификата. Также программа добавит задачу в `cron` для проверки срока истечения сертификата (90 дней) и его автоматического продления (для этого будут сгенерированы новые файлы и обновлена конфигурация (наверное))
4. Для `Tomcat` сложнее. Я не нашёл инструкцию по автоматической настройке, засим делаем вручную.

   **Инструкция для Ubuntu 18:**

   1. Копируем файлы приватного ключа, самого сертификата и цепочки (`privkey`, `cert`, `chain`) (у всех расширение - `pem`) в домашнюю папку юзера, который крутит `Tomcat`, выдав этому юзеру права на эти файлы.
   2. Прописываем в конфигурацию `Tomcat` (`server.xml`) пути до файлов так:

      ```
      <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
         maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
              <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
              <SSLHostConfig>
                  <Certificate certificateKeyFile="${user.home}/privkey.pem"
                   certificateFile="${user.home}/cert.pem"
                   certificateChainFile="${user.home}/chain.pem"
                   type="RSA" />
              </SSLHostConfig>
      </Connector>
      ```
   3. Перезапускаем `Tomcat`.

   **Инструкция для Debian 8:**

   1. Копируем файлы приватного ключа, самого сертификата и цепочки (`privkey`, `cert`, `chain`) (у всех расширение - `pem`) в домашнюю папку юзера, который крутит `Tomcat`, выдав этому юзеру права на эти файлы.
   2. [Создаём](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/using-lets-encrypt-with-tomcat/41082/2) `pfx` файл. Он нужен, т.к. по неизвестной мне причине Tomcat не хочет в данном случае принимать PEM файлы из-за каких-то там нативных либ, которые у меня не получилось настроить, т.к. инструкции, как всегда, для профи, обычный человек не разберётся.

      ```
      openssl pkcs12 -export -out bundle.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem -password pass:password
      ```
   3. Прописываем в конфигурацию `Tomcat` (`server.xml`) пути до файлов так:

      ```
      <Connector
         protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
         port="8443"
         maxThreads="200"
         scheme="https" 
         secure="true" 
         SSLEnabled="true"
         keystoreFile="${user.home}/bundle.pfx" 
         keystorePass="password"
         clientAuth="false"
         sslProtocol="TLS" 
         keystoreType="PKCS12"/>
      ```

Информация взята [отсюда](https://makedreamprofits.ru/blog/free-ssl/)